# force feedback in logitech G29 joystick

Tags: c++, joystick

I am using mmsystem.h to read joystick data in windows.  Following strucure is used for reading

```
typedef struct joyinfoex_tag {
  DWORD dwSize;
  DWORD dwFlags;
  DWORD dwXpos;
  DWORD dwYpos;
  DWORD dwZpos;
  DWORD dwRpos;
  DWORD dwUpos;
  DWORD dwVpos;
  DWORD dwButtons;
  DWORD dwButtonNumber;
  DWORD dwPOV;
  DWORD dwReserved1;
  DWORD dwReserved2;
} JOYINFOEX

JOYINFOEX joyInfoEx;
joyGetPosEx(0, &joyInfoEx);
```

I want to send force feedback to the joystick. Can any one help me to do this ?

Comment: AFAIK There is no support for force feedback in mmsystem at all. For that you can use direct input.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the available documentation, there does not seem to be direct support for controller FeedBack via the mmsystem interface.